# Group By and Selection of columns

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle

I have the following query

```
SELECT  McId, MAX(TimeDone) 
FROM    Trace 
WHERE   PcbId = 'C825514362' 
AND  DeviceId <> 0 GROUP BY McId
```

But I also need to get values from following columns `Program`,`DeviceId`,`OrderNo`

Is it possible to somehow combine that in the same query ?

This query should run under mssql , mysql and oracle.

Comment: what exactly you want with these additional columns.. 

please provide some data and expected result..

Comment: @pratik garg, just to get the data that in under those columns, like I do for McId

Comment: ohh then answer posted by iiro is what you are expecting .. 

In your description it was looking like you do not want to do without adding columns in group by clause ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  
 McId, 
 MAX(TimeDone),
 Program,
 DeviceId,
 OrderNo
FROM  Trace
WHERE   PcbId = 'C825514362' AND  DeviceId <> 0
GROUP BY 
 McId,
 Program,
 DeviceId,
 OrderNo
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, I'd guess that you want to get the values of Program, DeviceId and OrderNo for the row which contains the maximum of TimeDone. As far as I know, you have to do that with a subquery.
Something like that:

```
SELECT t.McID, t.Program, t.DeviceID, t.OrderNo, t.TimeDone
FROM Trace t,
   (SELECT MAX(TimeDone) as maxtime, McID
 FROM Trace 
 GROUP BY McID) maxresults
WHERE t.McID = maxresults.McID
AND t.TimeDone= maxresults.maxtime;
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the following construct?

```
SELECT McId, MAX(TimeDone),Program,DeviceId,OrderNo FROM Trace WHERE PcbId = 'C825514362' AND  DeviceId <> 0 GROUP BY McId,Program,DeviceId,OrderNo
```

Answer (score 0):

why cant you add Program,DeviceId,OrderNo to the group by?

If you answer that it will produce more lines because there are different values for "Program,DeviceId,OrderNo" than which of the values would you like to display?

you can always embed a subquery on you group by to get this values but again, if you have more than one possibility, you need to define the rule to come up with the program for example

```
SELECT  McId, MAX(TimeDone), 
        (select top 1 program from trace t2 where t2.McId = trace.McId) as program
FROM  Trace
WHERE   PcbId = 'C825514362' AND  DeviceId <> 0
GROUP BY McId
```

Answer (score 0):

Three solutions.

1. Considering you want the `MAX` of `Program,DeviceId,OrderNo`

   ```
   SELECT McId, 
          MAX(TimeDone),
          MAX(Program),
          MAX(DeviceId),
          MAX(OrderNo)
   FROM  Trace
   WHERE   PcbId = 'C825514362' AND  DeviceId  0
   GROUP BY McId;
   ```
2. Considering you want the remaining columns as comma separated with `~` as the separator

   ```
   SELECT McId, 
          MAX(TimeDone),
          GROUP_CONCAT('~', Program, '~', DeviceId, '~', OrderNo)
   FROM  Trace
   WHERE   PcbId = 'C825514362' AND  DeviceId  0
   GROUP BY McId
   ```
3. Considering you want to be grouped along with McId

   ```
   SELECT McId, 
          MAX(TimeDone),
          Program,
          DeviceId,
          OrderNo
   FROM  Trace
   WHERE   PcbId = 'C825514362' AND  DeviceId  0
   GROUP BY McId, Program, DeviceId, OrderNo;
   ```